# Create element using call_user_func in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have a PHP stuff that uses call_user_func to create element/objects to a certain function where it was place.

Example functions.php File:

```
    function head($args=null){

       echo $args;

    }

    function footer($args=null){

       echo $args;

    }

    function createHeadTexts(){

       echo 'This is header area';

    }

    function createFooterTexts(){

       echo 'This is footer area';

    }

    //function to call this elements
    function addParam($arg, $val){

       call_user_func($arg, call_user_func($val));

    }
```

Example index.php file:

```
    head()

    This is contents area...

    footer()
```

Back to my functions.php file, I have added a call to function which is

```
addParam('head','createHeadTexts')//which is I thought has to be added on a header area.
addParam('footer','createHeadTexts')//which is I thought has to be added on a footer area too.
```

But I came to an issue when I tried to view my PHP page.

it looks like this :

```
This is header area This is footer area 
This is contents area...
```

I thought the texts should be display like this:

```
This is header area 
This is contents area...
This is footer area
```

The only functions should be place to my index.php file is head() and footer().
The head() should be appear before the web contents, and footer() should be appear after the contents.

If I would like to create an element/objects/scripts to head() it should be addParam('head','function to create element/object/scripts');

Please help me how to fix this or is there any other way to use aside call_user_func?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, you are not outputting any new lines ( `\n` ) or HTML line break ( `<br>` ) - so why should it show each output on new lines?

Comment: The description of what you want is unclear. Do you want to call `addParam` before output starts and have the output each call generates appear in the appropriate place (nothing is output during the call to `addParam`)? Or do you instead want to call `addParam` at the appropriate place in the script where the output should appear? Something else? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Well, addParam() should be process in functions.php file perhaps and call a function and generate it to head() function or footer() function which I put to my index.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this and it came out allright:

```
<?php

function head($args=null){
    echo $args;
}

function footer($args=null){
    echo $args;
}

function createHeadTexts(){
    echo 'This is header area';
}

function createFooterTexts(){
    echo 'This is footer area';
}

// function to call this elements
function addParam($arg, $val){
    call_user_func($arg, call_user_func($val));
}

addParam('head','createHeadTexts');
echo '<br />This is contents area...<br />';
addParam('footer','createFooterTexts');

?>
```

And the output:

```
This is header area
This is contents area...
This is footer area
```

Maybe you forgot to change some arguments? The only thing I changed was

addParam('footer','createHeadTexts') to addParam('footer','create **FOOTER** Texts')

Comment: Sorry, but addParam() and the contents area should be on different files. the contents might be on the index.php file and addParam should be process in functions.php file. The only thing I need to put in the header is header() function and footer() for the footer area. Thanks for your reply

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put those functions, they will work the same. Insert them all nto functions.php file and call them with require_once('functions.php');

Comment: The head() and footer() functions should only on the index file. The rest of function is on the functions.php file. If I would like to add an element/scripts to head() function, It should be  addParam('head','function to create element or script') function and display it to head() area.